# form submission using struts1.x link tag

Tags: java, forms, struts-1

I am unable to submit form using `<html:link>` tag in struts 1.x

here is my case :

```
 <html:form action="">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
       <html:text property="firstName"></html:text>
    </td>
    <td>
       <html:text property="lastName"></html:text>
    </td>
    <td>
       <html:text property="middleName"></html:text>
    </td>
    <td>
       <html:text property="worstName"></html:text>
    </td>
    <td>
       <html:text property="goodName"></html:text>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
  <html:link action ="/someAction.do" >I am link </html:link>
</html:form>
```

and in my `struts-config.xml` I have configured my form and action

```
   <form:bean name="someForm"  class="someformclass">
     </form:bean>  
   <action name="someForm" path="/someAction" class="someactionclass">
      //some forwardings.
   </action>
```

But the thing here is I am unable to get the those form data (i.e all those names) in my form object what I get is just blank empty.

Is `<html:link  action="someAction">` tag is not supposed to carry `form data` ?

if so what is the difference between `<html:link href="someLink">` ?

if I want to submit the form with `<html:link >` tag with out java script how would I achieve ?

Comment: You don't; links are links, submits are submits. If you want to subvert a link to do a form submission then you'll use JavaScript.

Comment: Ohh Okay thank you but what about `action` attribute in `link` tag ?

Comment: What about it? It's still a link, not a form submit.

Comment: I am surprised why we have `action` and `href` attributes in link tag since both of them serves same service ?

Comment: Because they don't serve the same purpose; one is for an href, one is for an action.